# Show only selected or specific matplotlib figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I am generating a total of 50+ figures but I do not wish to display them all. I would like to pick out the figures that I want to display. Is there any way to do it?

For example: I have 50 plots which are generated over the course of the program. At the end, when I enter plt.show(), it shows all the figures. However, I would like to display only 3 or 4 figures (but they aren't fixed i.e, I could plot figures 1, 2, 3, 4 at one time and another time I could plot figures 10, 27, 33, 45). Also, a separate function is generating these figures and I am returning all the figures.

Sample main script:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from sampleplotfn import *


A = 1
omega = np.linspace(10,35,50)

for i in range(len(omega)):
    fig1 = sinewave(A,omega[i])

plt.show()
```

samplepltfn.py

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


def sinewave(A,omega):
      t = np.linspace(0,10,25)
      f = A*np.sin(omega*t)
      fig1 = plt.figure()
      plt.plot(f,t)
      return fig1
```

Comment: You could close the figures you don't want to see before you call `plt.show()`, ( `if (....) plt.close(fig1)` ).

Comment: But why do you need to plot them all ? Why can't you apply your decision criteria whatever it is before actually plotting the figure ?

Comment: Thanks @jeanrjc ! I wasn't thinking quite well at that time. I found a way to  plot only the figures that I wanted before plotting all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's going to be tricky to do what you want in a script; I agree with jrjc's comment - you should weed the plots you want before making them instead of trying to keep a ton of non-shown plots (they still take up memory and you have to remember to clean them up!).  If you are in interactive mode, you can show individual plots using the `show` method of the individual figures (e.g. `fig2.show()`), as long as you've made the figures using `plt.figure`, but in that case they would have been shown as they were created anyway.

Additionally, I would highly recommend against using pylab, and in particular, against using "plt" as an import alias for it.  "plt" is traditionally used for pyplot, not pylab. (`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`).  Pylab includes a ton of other stuff and is discouraged from use except for interactive work.

Lastly, you are overwriting "fig1" in your loop.  Try saving the figures into a list instead of a single variable.

Comment: `fig.show()` only works in interactive mode. OP is using a script.

Answer (score 8):

According that you have created 2 figures, but you want to show only the first one:

```py
import random

f1, a1 = plt.subplots()
a1.plot(random.sample(range(100), 20))

f2, a2 = plt.subplots()
a2.plot(random.sample(range(100), 20))
```

`f1.show()` will not work in a script.

As suggested in comments, you could instead close the figures you don't want to see before you call:

```py
plt.close(f2)
plt.show()
```

A more generic solution that work for a large number of figures is to iterate over all figures and close them, except the one you want to show:

```py
for fig_num in plt.get_fignums():
     if figure.number != fig_num:
         plt.close(figure.number)
plt.show()
```

Or, using generators:

```py
[plt.close(f) for f in plt.get_fignums() if f != f1.number]
plt.show()
```

Comment: What if I don't want to close the figures? Suppose a long script, possibly interactive, is generating fig1, but I want to plot and show a fig2 somewhere in-between before fig1 is ready? Feels like I should be able to do this.

Comment: Closing the figures also destroys them. In your example, creating f2 is utterly pointless.